# Send email with c# timed out

Tags: c#

The goal of my program is to send an email using visual studio.

Here is my code:

```
SmtpClient cv = new SmtpClient("smtp.outlook.com", 587);
cv.EnableSsl = true;
cv.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
cv.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("richardteunen2@hotmail.com", "password");
cv.Send("richardteuen2@hotmail.com", "ipadcraze@hotmail.com", "", "Hello");

MessageBox.Show("Done");
```

> System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The operation has timed out.
>       at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
>       at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(String from, String recipients, String subject, String body)

Any suggestions would be great. Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send email using Outlook.com SMTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18862932/send-email-using-outlook-com-smtp)

Comment: The Outlook.com SMTP server is `smtp-mail.outlook.com`. You are also missing some required settings.

Comment: could you please elaborate on missing settings?

Comment: Try to format the code as good as you can, also errors or exceptions using quote '>'. Its easier to read for other users.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to increase the timeout?

```
SmtpClient cv = new SmtpClient("smtp.outlook.com", 587);
            cv.EnableSsl = true;
            cv.Timeout = 2000;
            cv.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            cv.Credentials = new 
NetworkCredential("richardteunen2@hotmail.com", "password");
            cv.Send("richardteuen2@hotmail.com", "ipadcraze@hotmail.com", 
"", "Hello");
```

Comment: hi yes i have it still gives me the error andthe goes into and ifinite loop